# Firebird: simulating create table as?

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, firebird, temp-tables, create-table

I'm searching a way to simulate "create table as select" in Firebird from SP.

We are using this statement frequently in another product, because it is very easy for make lesser, indexable sets, and provide very fast results in server side.

```
create temp table a select * from xxx where ...
create indexes on a ...
create temp table b select * from xxx where ...
create indexes on b ...

select * from a
union
select * from b
```

Or to avoid the three or more levels in subqueries.

```
select * 
from a where id in (select id 
                    from b 
                    where ... and id in (select id from c where))
```

The "create table as select" is very good cos it's provide correct field types and names so I don't need to predefine them.

I can simulate "create table as" in Firebird with Delphi as:

Make select with no rows, get the table field types, convert them to create table SQL, run it, and make "insert into temp table " + selectsql with rows (without order by).
It's ok.

But can I create same thing in a common stored procedure which gets a select sql, and creates a new temp table with the result?

So: can I get query result's field types to I can create field creator SQL from them?

I'm just asking if is there a way or not (then I MUST specify the columns).

Comment: You can get the column definitions using using `select * from rdb$relation_fields where rdb$relation_name = 'A'` and then continue from there.

Comment: But what I can do with joined fields (select a.x, b.y from ....)? :-(

Comment: And what about to use Create View ..... as select?

Comment: No idea. You probably get better answers if you ask this on the Firebird mailing list.

Comment: Does create view supports the using indexes on subviews?
select * from view1, view2, view3 where ...

Comment: AFAIK, indeces are not supported on views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing DDL inside stored procedure is not supported by Firebird. You could do it using [EXECUTE STATEMENT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html) but it is not recommended (see the warning in the end of "[No data returned](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-nooutput)" topic).

One way to do have your "temporary sets" would be to use (transaction-level) [Global Temporary Table](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html). Create the GTT as part of the database, with correct datatypes but without constraints (those would probably get into way when you fill only some columns, not all) - then each transaction only sees it's own version of the table and data...